# WCF – netNamedPipeBinding, basicHttpBinding and IIS interaction

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services, iis, basichttpbinding

I'm trying to populate a method named getData() via the web service PasarelaService over IIS and WCF. At the same time, this service gets the data from a method named getDato(), via named pipe, inside a self-hosted independent-process named Multiplexor. All works fine, except when I call PasarelaService from IIS.

When I test the service with WcfTestClient,  directly from

```
http://localhost:49208/PasarelaService.svc
```

, avoiding IIS, all works fine and correct value is taken from Multiplexor, but when I test the same service via IIS, from

```
http://localhost:8001/PasarelaService.svc?wsdl
```

ever returns zero.

It seems that when I call the service in the first mode, a new instance of PasarelaService is created and the execution thread runs over the constructor and then over GetData(). But when I call the service from IIS, perhaps no instance is created and no constructor nor Initconexion() is executed. Only GetData() method is called but returns zero with no errors. I don't know why.

Pasarela code:

```
Imports Multiplexor

<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.Single)> _
Public Class PasarelaService
Implements IPasarelaService

' dato que suministramos al consumidor web
Private count As Integer

Dim proxy As IServiciosScreen = Nothing

Public Sub New()
    count = 0
    Me.InitConexion()
End Sub

Private Sub InitConexion()
    Try
        Dim ep As New EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/8100")
        proxy = ChannelFactory(Of IServiciosScreen).CreateChannel(New     NetNamedPipeBinding(), ep)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function GetData() As String Implements IPasarelaService.GetData
    Try
        count = proxy.GetDato()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    Return count.ToString()
End Function

End Class
```

Rellevant web.config from PasarelaService.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings />
<services>
  <service name="Pasarela.PasarelaService" behaviorConfiguration="Pasarela.PasarelaServiceBehavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Pasarela.IPasarelaService">
      <!--
          Antes de la implementación, se debe quitar o reemplazar el siguiente elemento de identidad para reflejar la 
          identidad bajo la que funciona el servicio implementado. Si se quita, WCF deducirá automáticamente una identidad 
          apropiada.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Pasarela.PasarelaServiceBehavior">
      <!-- Para evitar revelar información de los metadatos, establezca el valor siguiente en false antes de la implementación -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- Para recibir detalles de las excepciones en los fallos, con el fin de poder realizar la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true. Para no revelar información sobre las excepciones, establézcalo en false antes de la implementación -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: It looks like you would never see any exceptions, i am guessing that either init or get data is throwing. Either add logging or get rid of the try catch and set includeExceptionDetailInFaults to true

Comment: You are right. I was deleted all try...catch and now I can see inner error: No se encontr¢ el extremo de canalizaci¢n 'net.pipe://localhost/8100' en el equipo local. ("can't find net.pipe boundaries on local machine"). Why I can see http://localhost:49208/PasarelaService.svc but I can't see the same service from http://localhost:8001/PasarelaService.svc?wsdl ?

Comment: you are trying to set up a net.pipe connection to the service but all i see in the service config is basicHttpBinding